# Same Table, Two entities (or class) in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I'd like to build two class that refer to the same table.

For example:
Table Invoice:
idInvoice, IdClient, idProduct.

I've got one entity that shows general information (idClient and idInvoice) and than I've got an entity that allows me to show a dynamically generated form (id Product).

For every invoice I need one or more product so I should be able to insert different row for different product.

How can I link this different entities on the same table?
When I submit the form I need to extract all data from Product information and all data from Client and then I need to insert on MySQL.

I have got ORDER TABLE and PRODUCT TABLE. They are in a one to many relationship (one order, more product.) I created two entities: Order and Product and these are the classes:

ORDER CLASS

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="ordini")
*/

class Ordine
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */

protected $idOrdine;



    /**
     * 
     * @ORM\OnetoMany(targetEntity="Prodotto", cascade={"persist"},    
  mappedBy="prodotto")
     * 
     */
 protected $prodotti;

/**
 * Get idOrdine
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdOrdine()
{
    return $this->idOrdine;
}

public function __costruct() 
 {
$this->prodotti= new ArrayCollection(); 
}


 public function setProdotti(ArrayCollection $prodotti) 
 {
 $this->prodotti = $prodotti;
  //return $this;
 }


public function addProdotti(Prodotto $prod) {
$this->prodotti[] = $prod;
return $this;
}

public function addProdotto(Prodotto $prodotto) {
$this->prodotti[] = $prodotto;
$prodotto->setOrdine($this);
return $this;
}

public function getProdotti() {
return $this->prodotti;
}
}
```

PRODUCT CLASS

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="prodotto")
 */
class Prodotto
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $idProdotto;


 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=TRUE)
  * 
 */
protected $modello;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ordine", inversedBy="prodotti")
 *  @var AppBundle\Entity\Ordine
*/
  protected $ordini;



/**
 * Get idProdotto
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getIdProdotto()
{
    return $this->idProdotto;
}

/**
 * Set modello
 *
 * @param string $modello
 * @return Prodotto
 */
public function setModello($modello)
{
    $this->modello = $modello;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get modello
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getModello()
{
    return $this->modello;
}
}
```

Then I created a Form that allows me to create an order (invoice) and I can dynamically generate Product Field.
I should be on the right way but now it gives me an error:

> Expected argument of type "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection",
>       "array" given

My OrderForm is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Documentofiscale;
use Symfony\Component\Form\TextField;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Checkbox;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Prodotto;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


class FormDocumentoFiscale extends AbstractType
{

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
//    $builder->add('idCliente');
  //$builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'INSERISCI    
  DOCUMENTO'));
    $builder->add('prodotti', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new FormAggiuntaProdotti(),
       'allow_add'    => true,
       'by_reference' => false,
    )
           );

$builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'INSERISCI      
DOCUMENTO'));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Ordine',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'documento';
}
}
```

And my dynamically generated Form is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Documentofiscale;

use Symfony\Component\Form\TextField;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Checkbox;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Prodotto;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FormAggiuntaProdotti extends AbstractType
{

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('modello');
////    $builder->add('idCliente');
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Prodotto',
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'prodotto';
}
}
```

Comment: your question is quite difficult to understand. i think you are misusing the terminology. entity is representation of database table. therefore 1 database table = 1 entity. also you need to give us complete database structure. or is that (db structure) that you need help with ? also i think the form part is different question... you need to really reformulate the question. read this before: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: assuming your using Doctrine as DB ORM you can choose your favorite inheritance mapping. look at the documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you for suggest! I'll try to reformulate the question. I have got ORDER TABLE and PRODUCT TABLE. They are in a one to many relationship (one order, more product.) I created two entities: Order and Product and these are the classes:

Comment: i updated my question. Thank you